# Cygwin Not Recognizing Python Modules

Tags: python, windows, module, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin and Python2.7 and I have already installed some third party modules (PySide, PyGame) on my computer and when I run them using the normal GUI they work fine. But when I run python inside Cygwin it doesn't recognize the modules I already have installed. I'm using Windows 7 for this. Is there anyway I can get Cygwin to recognize these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not clear (e.g. what do you mean by "the normal GUI"), but it *sounds* like you installed Windows versions of Python and those extensions; those binaries won't work with the Cygwin version of Python.